# Getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException while running nightly builds

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, watin

Currently I have 2 virtual test servers(win2003). One is on which websites are deployed and other one has all the tests. I have setup all nightly build using cc.net. When ever I run tests on nightly builds. Some of the tests fail saying 
1. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA. 
2. While some got timeout exception. while some times testfixtures is not set up due to timeout on server.

Any one has any idea. Why it is causing this problem, is there any thing to do with synchronisation of 2 machines or any privileges or firewall restirction.

Kind regards

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464877/asp-net-unit-testing-watin-and-windows-7-internet-explorer-8/13085953#13085953).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the same System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException on one of my test. But for the timeout, i solved it by expanding the timeout property (WatiN 2.0)

```
[SetUp] \\for NUnit but you can change with you own testing engine
public void EachSetup()
{ 
 Settings.AutoCloseDialogs = true;
 Settings.AttachToIETimeOut = 300;
 Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 300;
 Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 300;
}
```